# How can I programmatically determine if a shapefile contains points, polygons, or lines?

Tags: arcgis-engine

How can I programmatically determine if a shapefile contains points, polygons, or lines?

ArcEngine 10, VS2010, C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can iterate through the geometry features and determine the type of the geometry feature in a conditional statement using the GetGeometryType method I suggest you go through the API found here: 
http://geoinformatics.tkk.fi/doc/Geo-GDAL/html/class_geo_1_1_o_g_r_1_1_geometry.html

Answer (score 6):

Searching for arcengine+shapetype will help you find: 
[IFeatureClass](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/java/arcengine/com/esri/arcgis/geodatabase/IFeatureClass.html)
Or much faster if you like: check byte 32-35 of the file
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: The problem with links to google in an answer (in general) is that there's a good chance that the #1 result in a little while will be this question. (Assuming this site will accumulate the sort of googlejuice that StackOverflow.com has...) Also, LMGTFY is a touch snarky, which I appreciate, but not everyone does. ;)

Comment: I've added the link which you are supposed to find. Using lmgtfy is educational here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [IFeatureclass.ShapeType](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ShapeType_Property/0025000002tp000000/).  Opening a featureclass is a bit expensive, I bet johanvdw's method is faster.